# Shuffle rows in pandas dataframe, keeping duplicates together

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby, shuffle

I have a data like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
35 1  2  35 25 65
40 5  7  47 57 67
20 1  8  74 58 63
35 1  2  37 28 69
40 5  7  49 58 69
20 1  8  74 58 63
35 1  2  47 29 79
40 5  7  55 77 87
20 1  8  74 58 63
```

Here we can see that Columns A,B and C have replicas that are repeated in various rows. I want to shuffle all the rows and have the replicas in consecutive rows, without deleting any of them. The output should look like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
35 1  2  35 25 65
35 1  2  37 28 69
35 1  2  47 29 79
40 5  7  47 57 67
40 5  7  49 58 69
40 5  7  55 77 87
20 1  8  74 58 63
20 1  8  74 58 63
20 1  8  74 58 63
```

When I use `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`, it can give me duplicated rows. How can I keep all the identical rows using `groupby`?

Comment: Or, if you don't need to sort on strictly ascending, or descending but would like to preserve the order of occurrence they appear in your `DataFrame`: `pd.concat([gp for _, gp in df.groupby(list('ABC'), sort=False)])`

Comment: BTW, in future, please don't forget to tag your Pandas questions with the generic python tag.

Comment: @ALollz This isn't pure sorting, it's shuffling, because in the example we get the A=35 rows, then 40, then 20.

Comment: I suggest your title needs a further edit, because you don't actually want shuffling either: *"Reorder rows in pandas dataframe according to first three columns, keeping duplicates together"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that achieves the result you asked for (which doesn't require either explicit shuffling or sorting, but merely grouping your existing df by columns A,B,C):

```
df_shuf = pd.concat( group[1] for group in df.groupby(['A','B','C'], sort=False) )

print(df_shuf.to_string(index=False))

A  B  C   D   E   F
35  1  2  35  25  65
35  1  2  37  28  69
35  1  2  47  29  79
40  5  7  47  57  67
40  5  7  49  58  69
40  5  7  55  77  87
20  1  8  74  58  63
20  1  8  74  58  63
20  1  8  74  58  63
```

Notes:

- I couldn't figure out how to do `df.reindex` in-place on the grouped object. But we can get by without it.
- You don't need `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`, since `df.groupby(['A','B','C']` puts all duplicates in the same group already.
- `df.groupby(... sort=False)` is faster, use it whenever you don't need the groups sorted by default.

Comment: @TranquilOshan: yes that's what I said. (I suspect `.reindex` in-place would probably be more CPU-and-memory-efficient if it could be gotten to work here, since we wouldn't need to send all the groups through a generator expression, then `concat` them)